# Slow Performance of Linq Where statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List` of `Objects` (roughly 100k) that is must iterate upon in order to produce a `Dictionary`.
however the code is performing very slowly, specifically on one line

```
public class Item{
        public int ID;
        public int Secondary_ID;
        public string Text;
        public int Number;
}
```

Data Looks something like (100k lines)

```
ID  | Secondary_ID |      Text       | Number
1   |    1         | "something"     | 3
1   |    1         | "something else"| 7
1   |    1         | "something1"    | 4
1   |    2         | "something2"    | 344
2   |    3         | "something3"    | 74
2   |    3         | "something4"    | 1
```

and i would like it to look like this when finished. (any collection will do to be honest)

```
 Dictionary<int, string> 

Key             | Value
(secondary_ID)  | (Text : Number)

1               | "Something : 3, Something else : 7, Something1 : 4"
2               | "Something2 : 344"
3               | "Something3 : 74, Something4 : 1"
```

My code currently works like this `ListAll` contains all data.

```
var Final=new Dictionary<int, string>();
var id1s=ListAll.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct().ToList();

foreach(var id1 in id1s) {
    var shortList=ListAll.Where(x => x.ID==id1).ToList(); //99% of time spent is here
    var id2s=shortList.Select(x => x.Secondary_ID).Distinct().ToList();

    foreach(var id2 in id2s) {
        var s=new StringBuilder();
        var items=shortList.Where(x => x.Secondary_ID==id2).ToList();

        foreach(var i in items) {
            s.Append(String.Format("{0} : {1}", i.Text, i.Number));
        }

        Final.Add(id2, s.ToString());
    }
}

return Final;
```

now the output is correct however as stated in the above comment, this takes an incredibly long time to process (90 seconds - certainly more than i am comfortable with) and was wondering if there is a faster way of achieving this.

This code is only going to be used once so is not really a normal usage and normally I would ignore it for that reason, but was wondering for learning purposes.

Comment: That is not your real code, is it ? Text, Number variable do not exist, and also you're not adding any comma to the stringbuilder...

Comment: Where is the input data? You may be able to get much better performance if you write an IQueryable that runs on e.g. the SQL database

Comment: You have quite a lot of redundant `ToList` calls.  There's no need to convert an `IEnumerable` to a list when the only thing you're going to do with it is iterate it in a `foreach` or call another LINQ method on it.  It's just wasting processor time and memory.

Comment: thanks for your responses, no this is not my real code it is a representation of it

Comment: I finally found that the problem is the code you've got just mess the things up. It is, in fact, a simple question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A much more efficient (and even easier to write) method of grouping the items by ID is to use `GroupBy`.

```
var query = ListAll.GroupBy(x => x.Secondary_ID)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key,
        group => string.Join(", ",
             group.Select(item => string.Format("{0} : {1}",item.Text , item.Number))),
    //consider refactoring part of this line out to another method
    });
```

As for the reason that your code is so slow, you're searching through the entire list for each distinct ID.  That's an O(n^2) operation.  `GroupBy` doesn't do that.  It uses a hash based structure internally, based on whatever you're grouping on, so that it can quickly (in O(1) time) find the bucket that any given item belongs in, as opposed to the O(n) time it takes your method.

Comment: @Magnus It is and it isn't.  The code at the levels nested further down have a higher asymptotic complexity (n^3) but that's not where he's saying the majority of his time is spent based on profiling.  Also note that the inner levels aren't based on the number of items in the list as a whole; n is based on the number of distinct IDs, so while that makes for a very high worst case, for his actual data it's quite possible that the inner levels really aren't the problem.  That said, if he didn't profile the code accurately the next level down could indeed be the problem.

Comment: this is fantastic thank you, I wanted to  use the to dictionary method initially but was not sure how to implement the string section string .join solves this

Comment: @Yakyb If there weren't an existing string method that did it for you it would be an appropriate place to create your own helper method that you call from within the lambda.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I would do (untested, but hopefully you get the idea):

```
var final = ListAll.GroupBy(x => x.Secondary_ID)
                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => String.Join(", ", 
                       x.Select(y => String.Format("{0} : {1}", 
                           y.Text, y.Number)))
```

This first groups by `Secondary_ID` using [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx), then puts the result into a dictionary using [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx).

The `GroupBy` will group your data into the following groups:

```
Key = 1:

ID  | Secondary_ID |      Text       | Number
1   |    1         | "something"     | 3
1   |    1         | "something else"| 7
1   |    1         | "something1"    | 4

Key = 2:
ID  | Secondary_ID |      Text       | Number
1   |    2         | "something2"    | 344

Key = 3:
ID  | Secondary_ID |      Text       | Number
2   |    3         | "something3"    | 74
2   |    3         | "something4"    | 1
```

Then the `.ToDictionary` method:

- Selects the key as `x.Key` (the key we grouped on, i.e. `Secondary_ID`).
- Selects the result of a `String.Join` operation as the value. What is being joined is the collection of "Text : Number" from the elements inside that group - `x.Select(y => String.Format("{0} : {1}", y.Text, y.Number)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove everywhere `ToList()`, it should becomes faster; because `ToList()` performs ***eager evaluation***.

I think what your code expects to do is:

```
var Final=new Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach(var x in ListAll)
    if(Final.ContainsKey(x.Secondary_ID))
        Final[x.Secondary_ID]+=String.Format(", {0} : {1}", x.Text, x.Number);
    else
        Final.Add(x.Secondary_ID, String.Format("{0} : {1}", x.Text, x.Number));

return Final;
```

***A*** `Dictionary` ***cannot contain a duplicate key***, so it's no matter here you use `ID` or `Secondary_ID`, if your `Secondary_ID` must be in the range of existing `ID`; and you even do not need `Distinct()` in the code.

By doing some simplification, original code would be:

```
foreach(var id1 in ListAll.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct()) {
    foreach(var id2 in ListAll.Where(x => x.ID==id1).Select(x => x.Secondary_ID).Distinct()) {
        var s=new StringBuilder();

        foreach(var i in ListAll.Where(x => x.ID==id1).Where(x => x.Secondary_ID==id2)) {
            s.Append(String.Format("{0} : {1}", i.Text, i.Number));
        }

        Final.Add(id2, s.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a `SortedDictionary` over a `Dictionary`?  It won't perform quite as well, and the results don't need to be sorted, which is the only reason you'd want to use one.